# Kafka: What happens when the entire Kafka Cluster is down?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We're testing out the Producer and Consumer using Kafka. A few questions:

- What happens when all the brokers are down and they're not responding at all?
- Does the Producer need to keep pinging the Kafka brokers to know when it is back up online? Or is there a more elegant way for the Producer application to know?
- How does Zookeeper help in all this? What if the ZK is down as well?

Answer (score 1):

If one or more brokers are down, the producer will re-try for a certain period of time (based on the settings). And during this time one or more of the consumers will not be able to read anything until the respective brokers are up.

But if the cluster is down for a longer period than your total re-try period, then probably you need to find a way to resend those failed messages again.

Answer (score 0):

Producer will fail because cluster will be unavailable, this means they will get a non retriable error from kafka client implementation and depending on your client process, message will buffer on the local send queue of your application.

I'm sure that if zookeeper is down your system will not work anymore. This is one of the weakness of Kafka, he need zookeeper to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one scenario where Kafka Mirroring(MirrorMaker tool) comes into picture.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27846330

Comment: Please provide more detail in your answer